# handling posted images using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to save multiple images at once using asp.net mvc4.
At view side I have 5 browse button and I'm successf. getting those file at the controller side as parameter at post action `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> postedPhotos`.

1. I want to know if `postedPhotos[0]` was sent, if so save it to the db.
2. iterate trough remaining postedPhotos collection and take further action only to those which actually contains photo (user can send only one or two image instead of five)

so I tried with

```
if(postedPhotos.First() != null)
foreach(var photo in postedPhotos.Where(x=>x.ContentLength>0))
{....}
```

but this doesn't work since I'm touching `postedPhoto` null value and I'm getting exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

ofcourse everything works if I send all five photos but I'm interesting how to handle this situation.

THanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if(postedPhotos != null && postedPhotos.FirsOrDefault() != null)
```

The difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` is that `First()` will throw an exception if there are no items in the collection while `FirstOrDefault()` just returns null.

You could also use `Any()` instead of `FirstOrDefault() != null`.

About your second question: it's not really clear to me what you want here. The `foreach` loop will only iterate if there are any items in the collection.

Comment: You don't need to test for `First()` or `Any()` or anything like that - just if `postedPhotos` itself is null. The foreach loop will only run if there's actually items in the list, so a check for `Any()` is essentially inherent.

Comment: True, but it seems to me that he wants to something different with the first photo than with the rest. It's not really clear to me though. I'll add your comment about the `foreach` loop to my answer.

Comment: @HenkMollema exactly I want to check if first item is not null and iterate trough every other which is not null

Comment: @panjo so does this answer your question? Or is something still unclear for you?

Comment: @panjo The first item, if any item exists at all, will never be null, so it's pointless to test for that. If `postedPhotos` is not null, then it is *at least* an empty list. You may then proceed into your foreach loop and if there's no items in that list, the foreach loop exits immediately.